# Usage of ConfigParser.setdefault()

Tags: python, python-3.6, configparser

I am trying to set default values on an instance of `configparser.ConfigParser` after its instantiation.
While inspecting the instance I found the method `ConfigParser.setdefault()`:

```
Help on method setdefault in module collections.abc:

setdefault(key, default=None) method of configparser.ConfigParser instance
    D.setdefault(k[,d]) -> D.get(k,d), also set D[k]=d if k not in D
```

While this is not very helpful at all, the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) does not even mention this *public* method.

So I started just to try-and-error:

```
>>> cp.setdefault('asd', 'foo')
<Section: asd>
>>> cp['asd']
<Section: asd>
>>> cp['asd']['foo']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1233, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'foo'
>>> cp['foo']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 959, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'foo'
>>> cp.setdefault('asd', {'foo': 'bar'})
<Section: asd>
>>> cp['asd']
<Section: asd>
>>> cp['asd']['foo']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1233, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'foo'
>>> cp['foo']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 959, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'foo'
>>>
```

But I could not figure out how to initialize a default section `'asd'` with a default key `'foo'` with value `'bar'`.

So my questions are:

1. <s>What is the method `ConfigParser.setdefault()` for?</s>
2. How can I set defaults on my `ConfigParser`'s instance after its initialization?

**Update**
After some further investigation it turned out that `ConfigParser.setdefault()` is inherited from `_collections_abc.MutableMapping`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConfigParser.setdefault` has nothing to do with setting the ConfigParser's defaults. If you want to set defaults, use the `DEFAULT` section, which provides defaults for other sections:

```
cp['DEFAULT']['key'] = 'value'
```

or if you configured a different `default_section`, use whatever you configured.

As described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#mapping-protocol-access),

> configparser objects behave as close to actual dictionaries as possible. The mapping interface is complete and adheres to the MutableMapping ABC. However, there are a few differences that should be taken into account:
>
> [list of differences, none of which involve `setdefault`]

`setdefault` is one of the operations specified by MutableMapping. `cp.setdefault('asd', 'foo')` attempts to set `cp['asd'] = 'foo'` if there is no entry for `cp['asd']`, then returns `cp['asd']`.

In a ConfigParser, an entry for `cp['asd']` would be an `'asd'` section, and it is not legal to set `cp['asd'] = 'foo'`. It is legal to set `cp['asd']` to a mapping, but you already had a `cp['asd']` section, so your `cp.setdefault('asd', {'foo': 'bar'})` call didn't do anything either.